# Embeded documentation in a Sails.js project

Tags: javascript, sails.js

When generating new models or controllers in Sails.js, they're created with:

```
/**
* Test.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/
```

This might be a stupid question, but what is the intended parser for such declarations?  Is there a built-in utility to generate this documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda-sorta [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/), although the @docs tag is non-standard.  There's no utility built in to Sails for generating those docs from the models themselves; it's just a message reminding you that you might want to document your code :)